# looking for a global "predispatch" method

Tags: session, typo3, typoscript

I would like to implemenent SSO in my typo3 project. I am looking for a method that is being called on every page so I can check if the user is already logged-in somewhere else.
Is there something like a global predispatch method that I can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a quite a few hooks within TYPO3 but from what you want to do I would highly recommend to add an authentication service. Take a look at extensions like EXT:px_hybrid_auth as a start.

Note: this is security sensitive, advanced stuff. Be careful!

Comment: I tried the px_hybrid_auth EXT but it throws a PHP Exception: " PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ... Configuration/TCA/tx_pxhybridauth_domain_model_identity.php line 5"   I will try with Hooks  then

Comment: You should not use it but see how they did the implementation. I doubt it might fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this TYPO3 Hook to check or manipulate fe user object.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['initFEuser'][] = 'MyVendor\\Ext\\Service\\UserService'
```